# Find out how much of my networking capacity I'm using?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, aws

On an AWS Ubuntu server I'm running a script that makes 1 million HTTP calls. I am considering whether or not to split it up into parallel processes. Is there some way I can see a graph of my usage vs the capacity?

Answer (score 2):

In AWS Console, select the running EC2 instance, then go to the Monitoring tab of the Instance Details panel, you can find network usage (network in & out).

The capacity depends on the type of your EC2 instance (T1, C3 etc). Check if you can find something from [Instance Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#AvailableInstanceTypes).

Comment: Thanks. I need to ask a coworker to do this for me - although I can SSH in, I don't have console management credentials. This is probably the most sensible solution, although I was curious if there was some way to do it from the command line.

Comment: Use `iftop` from commandline. This will display to you the current networking throughput of your VM, however you won't be able to view your current capacity this way. But as stated above you can search AWS docs to find out what capacity your instance size should have